# there is a problem in the intializtion of a variable in my code

Tags: java

The piece of code I created is called wheel of fortune guessing game, but the code puts an error at line 107 saying that choice is not initialized, but I am sure I initialized.

Here is the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class WheelOfFortune {

    private String phrase;
    private String guessedLetters;

    public WheelOfFortune(String phrase) {
        this.phrase = phrase.toUpperCase();
        this.guessedLetters = "";
    }

    public void displayPhrase() {
        for (int i = 0; i < phrase.length(); i++) {
            char letter = phrase.charAt(i);
            if (Character.isWhitespace(letter) || guessedLetters.indexOf(Character.toUpperCase(letter)) != -1) {
                System.out.print(letter);
            } else {
                System.out.print("*");
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    public boolean guessLetter(char letter) {
        letter = Character.toUpperCase(letter);

        if (!Character.isLetter(letter)) {
            System.out.println("Invalid input. Please enter a letter.");
            return false;
        }

        if (guessedLetters.indexOf(letter) != -1) {
            System.out.println("You've already guessed this letter.");
            return false;
        }

        guessedLetters += letter;
        return true;
    }

    public boolean hasGuessedEntirePhrase() {
        for (int i = 0; i < phrase.length(); i++) {
            char letter = phrase.charAt(i);
            if (Character.isLetter(letter) && guessedLetters.indexOf(letter) == -1) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static void clearScreen() {
        System.out.print("\033[H\033[2J");
        System.out.flush();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a phrase or word: ");
        String inputPhrase = scanner.nextLine().toUpperCase();

        WheelOfFortune game = new WheelOfFortune(inputPhrase);

        System.out.println("Welcome to Wheel of Fortune!");

        

        do {
            int choice;
            clearScreen(); // Clear the console screen
            System.out.println("Guessed letters: " + game.guessedLetters);
            System.out.println("\n-------------------------");
            game.displayPhrase();

            System.out.println("\nChoose an option:");
            System.out.println("1. Guess a letter");
            System.out.println("2. Guess the whole phrase");
            System.out.println("3. Quit");
            System.out.print("Enter your choice: ");

            String choiceStr = scanner.nextLine();

            if (choiceStr.matches("[1-3]")) {
                 choice = Integer.parseInt(choiceStr);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Invalid choice. Please select a valid option.");
                continue;
            }

            if (choice == 1) {
                System.out.print("Guess a letter: ");
                char letter = scanner.nextLine().charAt(0);
                game.guessLetter(letter);
            } else if (choice == 2) {
                System.out.print("Guess the whole phrase: ");
                String guess = scanner.nextLine().toUpperCase();
                if (guess.equals(game.phrase)) {
                    clearScreen(); // Clear the console screen one last time
                    System.out.println("Congratulations! You guessed the phrase: " + game.phrase);
                    break;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Incorrect guess. Keep playing.");
                }
            } else if (choice == 3) {
                clearScreen(); // Clear the console screen one last time
                System.out.println("Thanks for playing!");
            }
        } while (choice != 3 && !game.hasGuessedEntirePhrase());

        if (game.hasGuessedEntirePhrase()) {
            System.out.println("Congratulations! You guessed the entire phrase: " + game.phrase);
        }

        scanner.close();
    }
}
```

I tried to initialize inside the do while loop, but it still errors. I am pretty much stumped.

Comment: Which line is #107? The compiler points to the exact line, so you can add a comment in the code that identifies it. We're not going to count them.

Comment: also, quote the exact error message. Because the error message I get when I paste this code says that "choice cannot be resolved to a variable", which is quite different from not being initialized.

Comment: The _choice_ variable cannot be resolved, in this code.

Answer (score 1):

The issue in the given code lies not in initialization of the variable but in the place of declaring it (`Cannot resolve symbol 'choice'`). The variables declared inside the do-while block are out-of-scope for the condition expression.

So you can re-write the code to move the declaration of `choice` variable can be moved outside of the do-while block or add a `break` statement as required in the block retaining the declaration of the variable as is.

```
// moving the variable declaration outside the loop
int choice = 0;
do {
   // logic..
} while (choice != 3 && !game.hasGuessedEntirePhrase())
```

or

```
do {
    int choice = 0;
    // logic..
    else if (choice == 3) {
        // code for this condition
        break;
    }
} while (true)
```

Answer (score 0):

When I tried to compile this, I got this:

```
$ javac WheelOfFortune.java 
WheelOfFortune.java:108: error: cannot find symbol
        } while (choice != 3 && !game.hasGuessedEntirePhrase());
                 ^
  symbol:   variable choice
  location: class WheelOfFortune
1 error
```

This is the **primary** problem in your code.  To be specific, `choice` is declared in the body of the loop, and it is not in scope in `while` condition at the end of the loop.

You need to declare `choice` **before the start of the loop**.

Having done that, you are likely to run into the initialization issue again.  Why?  Because there is a path in the code where you get to the `while` condition without initializing `choice`.  It goes like this

1. Declare `choice` with no initial value.
2. Start the loop.
3. `String choiceStr = scanner.nextLine();` reads say "XYZ".
4. `choiceStr.matches("[1-3]")` evaluates to `false`
5. You take the `else` branch, print a message and `continue`.
6. Try to evaluate `choice != 3` in the `while` condition.

If you examine the code carefully, you will see that there is nothing assigning a value to `choice` *in this execution path*.  Its actual value is indeterminate.  Therefore, the compiler will tell you that the variable may not have been initialized.

What is the solution to *this* aspect of your problem?  There are two approaches you could consider.

- You could simply initialize `choice` to (say) `-1` in the declaration.  (In fact, any number other than `3` would work.)
- In step 4 above you could assign (say) `-1` to `choice` before the `continue` statement.

I will it leave it to you to analyze your code to work out why both of these solutions will work ... and decide which one is better.

---

<sup>(What I don't understand is why you got the error about the uninitialized variable when the variable was out of scope.  I can think of two possible explanations.  The first one is that you have confused your IDE's embedded compiler and it is giving a bogus error message.  The second one is that the code you showed us is different to the code that you compiled to get that error message!)</sup>